# JaxB - unmarshal an unwrapped objects list as a collection

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

Have got an epic REST API with the XML response type that has an unwrapped collection of objects at the `root` element.

It looks like this:

```
<root>
  <carName>Car1</carName>
  <carNumber>1</carNumber>
  <carType>SAV1</carType>
  <carName>Car2</carName>
  <carNumber>2</carNumber>
  <carType>SAV2</carType>
  <carName>Car3</carName>
  <carNumber>3</carNumber>
  <carType>SAV3</carType>
  <count>3</count>
</root>
```

I'm trying to unmarshal this as a `List` of child `Car` objects:

```
@XmlRootElement
public Root {

  @XmlElement
  private List<Car> cars;

  @XmlElement(name = "count")
  private Integer count;

  ...
}
```

... where the `Car` is the simple jaxb bean with `@XmlElement(name = "...")` annotation per the each it's primitive typed field. However, all the fields except of `count` are `null`.

Have tried to use the construction like this instead of nameless `@XmlElement`:

```
@XmlElements({
  @XmlElement(name = "carName", type = String.class),
  @XmlElement(name = "carNumber", type = Integer.class),
  @XmlElement(name = "carType", type = String.class)
})
```

... now I've got a 9 items array instead of 3, where's the each field of child `Car` class is stored as an independent array item.

So, the question is how to unmarshall XML structure like this to the well presented POJO `List`?

Comment: Have you looked at custom marshaling like Xmladapter?

Comment: @efekctive, gonna look into, thanks